# Insert non-default constructed element in std::map

Tags: c++

this is probably a damn straightforward question. But I can't seem to insert my object into a map. I'm pretty sure I do not have to define my own copy constructor, as I solely using standard stuff. Feel like banging my head against a wall now :lol:, this is the map I am trying to create:

```
map<unsigned, Vertex> vertexes;
```

Header file of Vertex:

```
    #ifndef KNOTSV2_VERTEX_H
    #define KNOTSV2_VERTEX_H

    #include <forward_list>
    #include <set>
    #include <iostream>

    #include "VertexType.h"

    using namespace std;

    // Defines.
    typedef tuple<edge_list, edge_list, edge_list> neigh_set_entry;


    /*
     * Matching
     */
    struct match_first {
        match_first(unsigned value) : value(value) {};

        template<class A>
        bool operator()(const pair<unsigned, A> &a) {
            return a.first == value;
        }
    private:
        unsigned value;
    };


    class Vertex {
    public:
        /*
         * Constructors
         */
        Vertex(unsigned identifier, VertexType *type, unsigned attributes) : identifier(identifier), type(type), values(attributes_vec(attributes)) {};

// Methods ..
    private:
        /*
         * Members
         */
        unsigned identifier;
        attributes_vec values;
        VertexType *type;
        vector<pair<unsigned, neigh_set_entry>> neigh_set;
    };
```

Function i am trying to call:

```
Vertex& Graph::create_vertex(VertexType &type) {
    Vertex v(id_enumerator++, &type, type.num_attributes());
    return vertexes[id_enumerator] = v;
}
```

> note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map, std::__1::allocator > >::operator[]' requested here

```
return vertexes[id_enumerator] = v;

               ^
```

> note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided

```
class Vertex {
      ^
```

> note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable:
>
> note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 0 were provided
>       Vertex(unsigned identifier, VertexType *type, unsigned attributes) : identifier(identifier), type(type), values(attributes_vec(attributes)) {};

So I understand it is due to the fact that it tries to call the 'normal constructor', but I don't want to create getter and setters for the values am passing to the constructor; as they may not be changed. As a second attempt I tried to use map::emplace, but no luck there either. Is there any other option besides creating a normal constructor?

Tried emplace and insert and pairwise construct, no luck either.

```
Vertex& Graph::create_vertex(VertexType &type) {
    //Vertex v();
    return vertexes.insert(make_pair(id_enumerator, Vertex(id_enumerator, &type, type.num_attributes()))).first->second;
}

Vertex& Graph::create_vertex(VertexType &type) {
    //Vertex v();
    return vertexes.emplace(id_enumerator, Vertex(id_enumerator, &type, type.num_attributes())).first->second;
}
Vertex& Graph::create_vertex(VertexType &type) {
    //Vertex v();
    return vertexes.emplace(piecewise_construct, forward_as_tuple(id_enumerator), forward_as_tuple(id_enumerator, &type, type.num_attributes())).first->second;
}
```

Comment: What compiler errors do you get when trying `insert` and `emplace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [`std::map::emplace`'s documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

> The constructor of the new element (i.e. `std::pair<const Key, T>`) is called with exactly the same arguments as supplied to emplace, forwarded via `std::forward<Args>(args)...`.

```
struct Vertex 
{
    Vertex(unsigned identifier, int type, unsigned attributes) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::map<unsigned, Vertex> vertexes;

//                       Vertex
//                       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    vertexes.emplace(0u, Vertex{0u, 1, 0u});
//                   ^^
//       const unsigned
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8lJACrQeTXFguOgu)